# I can't install any package because of beepr package error

Tags: r, installation

I keep getting this error whenever I open rstudio.

> Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’

Even, when I tried installing the package itself, I get the same error!
Not just this, I was trying to install other packages on R and I couldn't because of the same error!

Edit:

I tried installing beepr package

```r
install.packages("beepr")
```

and it gave that error

```r
also installing the dependencies ‘glue’, ‘magrittr’, ‘stringi’, ‘stringr’, ‘audio’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/glue_1.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 99049 bytes (96 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 96 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/magrittr_2.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 265580 bytes (259 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 259 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stringi_1.7.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7599762 bytes (7.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 7.2 MB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stringr_1.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 135777 bytes (132 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 132 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/audio_0.1-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 57390 bytes (56 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 56 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/beepr_1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 922244 bytes (900 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 900 KB
Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glue’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘magrittr’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘audio’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘beepr’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp0CeBTl/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning in install.packages :
  converting NULL pointer to R NULL
Warning message:
R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

Comment: Please show the output from `install.packages("beepr")`.

Comment: Do you have a `.Rprofile` file in your home directory which is automatically loaded packages for you?

Comment: @r2evans It tries to install other packages as a requirement for it and at the same time gives the same error of not having "beepr" installed. That's one of the packages it tried to install. 

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glue’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’
Execution halted

and it does that with the rest of the packages.

Comment: @MrFlick No, I don't have that file. I'm using rstudio through a conda environment.

Comment: What happens when you run `install.packages("glue")`? Also, your issue is unrelated to the Rstudio IDE.

Comment: @Phil It gives an error for not having (beepr) installed too


`Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glue’ had non-zero exit status`

That's the error I get when I try installing (glue)

Comment: I'll be literal: please [edit] your question and add a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that includes the command `install.packages("beepr")` and all of the text (messages, warnings, and errors) that occur from that command. It usually doesn't fail with no error, though sometimes they may seem obscure.

Comment: @r2evans I edited the question and added the error I got

Comment: ... have you somehow integrated `beepr` into your prompt and/or system bell?

Comment: @r2evans Nope, I didn't.

Comment: I can see no reason why R would complain about `library(beepr)` on every installation attempt unless it has been integrated as an error-indicator or such. I suggest trying to install it in a restarted and vanilla instance of R, no packages loaded. That is, restart R, verify that `sessionInfo()` does not list `beepr` in any way, then try to install it again. Sorry, though, I don't use `beepr` (nor RStudio), and I suspect that there's something fundamental to one or the other that I don't understand.

Comment: @r2evans I changed my working directory to
`cd ~` 
and when I opened rstudio, it didn't give the beepr loading error.
However, it gave me another error for loading (Seurat) package

Comment: @r2evans I added another question about loading Seurat error